# Why destructor getting called even though I have allocated memory using malloca?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;`
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        cout<<"Destructor called"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ///constructor called
    Test *t=new Test();
    free(t);
    Test *t2=(Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test));
    ///destructor getting called
    delete t2;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O/p:                                                                                                      constructor called                                                                                            
Destructor called

Comment: Instead of using ` to format the code you should prefix all the code lines in the questions with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semantics of `delete t2` is to call the destructor and then to free the space.

Here your code has undefined behavior since you cannot use the `free` function to free the space allocated by `new`. You can neither use the `delete` keyword to free the space allocated by `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't even compile:
malloc return a pointer to the memory that been allocated, so instead of:

```
Test t2=(Test)malloc(sizeof(Test));
```

You need to do

```
Test * t2=(Test*)malloc(sizeof(Test));
```

malloc is in c and delete is in C++.

After 'malloc'/'calloc' comes 'free'. 'free' only releases memory.

After 'new' comes 'delete'. 'delete' calls the destructor and then releases memory.

Comment: I am returning (Test*).